# Intercept and Redirect Entity save from within SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I currently have a table in the database that is structured like the following:

```
Orders
    OrderId int , --Primary Key
    CustomerId int,
    PartId int,
    OrderDate Date,
    Quantity int
```

Unfortunately because OrderId was set as the primary key instead of having a composite key of CustomerId, PartId, and OrderDate we have many instances of the following in the database:

```
OrderId | CustomerId | PartId | OrderDate  | Quantity
1       | 23         | 45     | 2016-11-16 | 1
2       | 23         | 45     | 2016-11-16 | 1
3       | 23         | 45     | 2016-11-16 | 1
4       | 26         | 30     | 2016-10-25 | 1
5       | 26         | 30     | 2016-10-25 | 1
```

Instead of:

```
OrderId | CustomerId | PartId | OrderDate  | Quantity
1       | 23         | 45     | 2016-11-16 | 3
4       | 26         | 30     | 2016-10-25 | 2
```

I'm not authorized to update the database due to regulatory/logging issues and an update would break legacy code. I however have convinced my boss to allow me to update Entity to enforce these constraints on any data moving forward.

My idea is to override `SaveChanges` in `DbContext` so that if the legacy code tries to add another row, where the `CustomerId`, `PartId`, and `OrderDate` already exists, that save is cancelled and the `Quantity` column of the existing row is increased. So far I have the following but am unsure how to cancel the save, update the existing row and force that row to save from within `SaveChanges`.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{

    var PartAssemblyList = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                            .Where( x => x.Entity is Order &&
                                         x.State == EntityState.Added);

    foreach (var entity in PartAssemblyList)
    {
        if (/*RowExists*/)
        {
            //Cancel Save (entity.State = EntityState.Unchanged)?
            //Update Quantity of Existing Row
            //Set existing row to save
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This sounds to me like something that should be implemented as business logic one layer above. Whatever class is using the context to add the row should be modified to look for the row first and increase the count if it exists. I understand you may not be able to modify that code but I am just saying. IMHO, you are opening a can of worms trying to override the behavior of SaveChanges. What do you gain by doing this? What's the downside of leaving it as is? (aside from the obvious). If storage is not an issue, I am with your boss. Leave as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that overriding EF is a bad idea because you could use it with other entities other than `Orders`. However why don't you wrap the `SaveChanges()` call and make the add/update job yourself ?

```
public void AddUpdateOrder(Order o)
{
    using(var ctx = new YourDataModelContext())
    {
        if(ctx.Orders.Any(x => x.OrderId == o.OrderId && x.CustomerId == o.CustomerId && x.PartId == o.PartId && x.OrderDate == o.OrderDate))
        {
            var e = ctx.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == o.OrderId && x.CustomerId == o.CustomerId && x.PartId == o.PartId && x.OrderDate == o.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault();
            e.Quantity += 1;
            ctx.Entry(e).State = Modified; 
        }
        else
        {
            Order e = new Order() { OrderId = o.OrderId, CustomerId = o.CustomerId, PartId = o.PartId, OrderDate == o.OrderDate, Quantity = 1};
            ctx.Orders.Add(e);
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think i was going to complicated with editing SaveChanges. This is the best way to go.